# How do you run and display output from a console to a rich text box in a winform?

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a winform that when launched the console also launches but disappears (Goes invisible). Then the code from it gets displayed in a rich text box. (Also the console is run through a .cs file) I'm kinda new to c# so sorry if i don't understand!

Comment: Do you want to redirect console output of another application to your UI or what do you mean by "the console"?

Comment: Place breakpoint at static void Main() method in Program.cs file and start debugging from there by pressing F-11 key you'll get it by your-self